# How to copy CentOS server using SSH from one hosting to AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws, amazon

I have like 15 VPS CentOS machines with SSH access on one hosting and I need to move them all to Amazon Web Services to EC2

That hosting is not supporting anything expect of SSH

Which the easiest options do I have to move them to AWS?

Comment: My recommendation would be to build entirely new servers on AWS and just move the optimizations over from the other hosting service. You really don't need to move an entire OS when you're really restricting your search to the 1% that is actually changed.

Comment: @doneal24 there is so much software and configs installed on each on these servers for the latest 10 years not by me, so I'll spend the entire month to do it again

Comment: If they are 10 years old it will be CentOS 4 or something like that. Probably unpatched, full of vulnerabilities, running old versions of software. You should *really* start afresh and migrate just the *data*.

Comment: @MLu they upgraded all the software every month, so it's up-to-date right now
I'm asking about the technical possibility to create somehow image from the server using SSH and then create EC2 from that image or something like that

Comment: You can use `rsync -PrvaSH {remote-server}:/ `. That will copy all the files across. Still I don’t think it’s a good idea. Take this opportunity to untangle all the 10 years old stuff and do it right.

Comment: @MLu my customer doesn't have a budget to pay for like 200-400 hours for that, he just wants to move everything "as is" from one hosting to another

Comment: @Artik If the OS was installed 10 years ago then it is out of support. How are you keeping it patched? If you're rebuilding RPMs, then you can move your rebuild process to the new servers and be done. Also, 200-400 hours to build a server?! That seems very excessive.

Comment: @Artik Could you do something like this to install the new OS? On the old server run `yum list installed | awk '{ print $1 }' > installed.txt` and `scp installed.txt remote-server:`. Then on the new system run `yum install $(< install.txt)`. You'll still need to copy over config files but all of the repository packages should be there.

Comment: @doneal24 there are 15 of that servers

Comment: @Artik And it takes you 400 hours to run this command for 15 servers?

Comment: @doneal24 there is too much everything that is not so easy to transfer in this way. I think how to create 100% duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments above...

1. What's the reason for moving from the current VPS hosting to AWS?

   AWS *is not* a simple VPS provider. Yes it can run Linux VMs but like-for-like-specs are often more expensive comparing to many VPS providers. So there must be some other driver behind this migration other than cost - **what is it?**
2. Those 15 VMs installed 10 years ago are now way out of support, they haven't been patched (because patches for 10 years old systems are no longer being published) and are full of vulnerabilities.
3. Servers that have been manually maintained for the last 10 years are for sure a horrible mess of entangled applications and inconsistent configurations. They are not worth keeping and migrating, they should be *configured again* on a fresh, new, supported systems.
4. If your client doesn't have budget to **do it right** I would question whether to do it at all? Even if AWS is cheaper than your current VPS (which is unlikely) it won't be that much cheaper to justify many man-hours spent for the migration. The ROI won't be great.

To wrap up: you should aim to **migrate only the data** and some customised configs but not anything else. That will enable you to 1) understand what's running where, and then 2) split the services to independent servers for easier maintenance.

What you're trying to do as described in the question is a bad idea, trust me ;)

Comment: There is legal reason why we should move old servers to AWS (we need to move it to any new hosting but we can't keep in on old)
We will abandon them in a half year because we are writing now new system from the scratch on the new servers, but he need to use the old system for that time